# Android O - Accessibility service - fingerprint gesture callback

Tags: accessibility, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to use the new fingerprint gesture callback from android O.

I've declared these in the manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
```

My accessibility service xml looks like this:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
                   android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
                   android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFingerprintGestures"
                   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
                   android:notificationTimeout="100"
                   android:canRetrieveWindowContent="false"
                   android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="false"
                   android:settingsActivity="com.example.finger.MainActivity"/>
```

..and then in the accessibility service onServiceConnected method I'm trying to register a callback with the following

```
 FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback callback = new 
 FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback(){

            @Override
            public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                LogUtil.d("available: " + available);
                super.onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(available);
            }

            @Override
            public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {
                LogUtil.d("gesture: " + gesture);
                super.onGestureDetected(gesture);
            }
        };

 FingerprintGestureController controller = 
 this.getFingerprintGestureController();
 controller.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(callback, null);
```

The accessibility service registers fine and the code above to register the callback gets called ok, but I never get a call to the onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged and onGestureDetected

The documentation around it is somewhat lacking so I'm not sure what else I need to be able to get the callback working.

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add                        `android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"` to the xml file

Comment: Didn't worked for me:

<service
            android:name="android.gestures.MyService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: It seems obvious why, the parameter must be inserted in the XML, not in the manifest

Comment: I tried it in XML as well but still not getting any callbacks.
protected void onServiceConnected() {
FingerprintGestureController gestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();
Log.e(TAG, "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable() ); // This always returns FALSE even though swipes are enabled in system and through accessibility as well
}

Comment: I posted new question with all my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125945/android-o-fingerprint-gesture-callback-not-working