# isGestureDetectionAvailable() always returns 'FALSE' on android 28

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-gesture

I have built an app which lets the user control their scrolling action using the fingerprint sensor.

It used to work earlier until some weeks back, where I found that **method: isGestureDetectionAvailable() always returns 'False'** after starting 'accessibility service'

Since I am getting 'isGestureDetectionAvailable()' as always 'False',
my 'registerFingerprintGestureCallback' doesn't work and hence all my functionality of swiping gestures.

Can Someone please help and point out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code.

```
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();

 FingerprintGestureController gestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();

 Log.e(TAG, "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable());

 FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback callback = new

 FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback() {

                public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                    super.onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(available);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged " + available);
                }


                public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {

                    switch (gesture) {
                        case FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_UP:
                            scrollDown();
                            break;
                        case FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN:
                            scrollUp();
                            break;
                        case FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT:
                            execute_swipe_right_functionality();
                            break;
                        case FINGERPRINT_GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT:
                            execute_swipe_left_functionality();
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.e("My Service",
                                    "Error: Unknown gesture type detected!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

    gestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(callback, new Handler());
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I set my code up basically the same way as this, and what's described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125945/android-o-fingerprint-gesture-callback-not-working

It all looks correct according to the Android docs, but isGestureDetectionAvailable() always returns false.

Comment: @DanePowell Have you solved it?