# Fingerprint gesture availability always false for android 9

Tags: android, gesture, fingerprint

I'm trying to use fingerprint gestures in an accessibility service. It is working fine in android 8.1 devices (Nexus 5x emulator, Moto G5s Plus) but not working in android 9 devices (Nexus 5x emulator, Samsung M30s). I've added all the required lines mentioned in this question:

[Android O - fingerprint gesture callback not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125945/android-o-fingerprint-gesture-callback-not-working)

Do I have to add something extra for android 9? Can someone please help me?

activity_service.xml:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:canRequestFingerprintGestures="true"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestFingerprintGestures"
android:canPerformGestures="true"/>
```

MyAccessibilityService.java:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

private static final String TAG = MyAccessibilityService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onInterrupt");
}

@Override
protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onGesture " + gestureId);
    return super.onGesture(gestureId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyEvent " + event.getKeyCode());
    return super.onKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        FingerprintGestureController gestureController = getFingerprintGestureController();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "Is available: " + gestureController.isGestureDetectionAvailable() );

        FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback callback = new
                FingerprintGestureController.FingerprintGestureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(boolean available) {
                        super.onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged(available);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gesture available change to: " + available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetectionAvailabilityChanged " + available);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGestureDetected(int gesture) {

                        super.onGestureDetected(gesture);
                        switch (gesture){
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN:
                                CameraManager mCameraManager;
                                mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                                String mCameraId = "";
                                try {
                                    mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                                    mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e){

                                }
                                break;
                            case GESTURE_SWIPE_UP:
                                mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                                try {
                                    mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                                    mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e){

                                }
                                break;
                                default:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                                            , "Gesture: " + gesture, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onGestureDetected " + gesture);
                    }
                };

        gestureController.registerFingerprintGestureCallback(callback, new Handler());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind " );
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.bignerdranch.com.myapplication">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission." />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <application>
        <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/activity_service" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share what you have tried so far in order to solve this issue, maybe provide a relevant code snippet for YOUR CODE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line in the gesture service xml

android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestFingerprintGestures"

It could also be device related. Check the following answer for information.
[Android M FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on a Samsung Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)

Can you provide your code samples for further debugging if this doesn't work?

Comment: It looks like I've already added this line. I've edited my question to include all my code now. Please look over it.